# How can I get input value from gridmvc where input is a part of grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```html
@Html.Grid(Model).Columns(Columns =>
            {
                Columns.Add(g => g.Cod_Sit, true);
                Columns.Add(g => g.Site.Lib_Sit, true);
                Columns.Add(g => g.Ref_Pro, true);
                Columns.Add(g => g.Cod_Fou).SetWidth("6%").Titled("Code Frs").Filterable(true);
                Columns.Add(g => g.Fournisseur.Rai_Soc).SetWidth("14%").Titled("Fournisseur").Filterable(true);
                Columns.Add(g => g.Rayon.Lib_Ray).SetWidth("12%").Titled("Rayon").Filterable(true);
                Columns.Add(g => g.Cod_Int).SetWidth("8%").Titled("Code Article").Filterable(true);
                Columns.Add(g => g.Article.Lib_Art).SetWidth("20%").Titled("Article").Filterable(true);
                Columns.Add(g => g.Qte_Sto).SetWidth("8%").Titled("Stock Dispo").Filterable(true).Css("numbers").Format("{0:N0}");
                Columns.Add(g => g.Qte_Enc).SetWidth("8%").Titled("Encours").Filterable(true).Css("numbers").Format("{0:N0}");
                Columns.Add(g => g.Qte_The).SetWidth("8%").Titled("Propos Syst").Filterable(true).Css("numbers").Format("{0:N0}");

                Columns.Add().Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).SetWidth("8%").RenderValueAs(o => **@<input id="idQte" name="idQte" , type="text" />);**
                }).WithMultipleFilters().Sortable(true).Named("GridGrille")
```

```js
  <script>
        $('#btnok').click(function () {
            var items = $(".grid-mvc").find(".grid-table > tbody").children();
            $.each(items, function (i, row) {
                alert($(row).children()[11].innerText);
            })
        })
    </script>
```

So I want to get the value from input and insert it into MS SQL Database. But by the way I do it, I got an undefined